# Multiple SQL query not working with delimiter on DBeaver

Tags: mysql, sql, pentaho, dbeaver

I can't execute MySQL statement when using delimiter (default ';'). I mean, when I run query like:

```
select * from mdw.dim_date dd limit 10;
select * from mdw.dim_order do limit 5;
```

I've got such error:

> SQL Error [1064] [42000]: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select * from mdw.dim_order do limit 5' at line 2

I don't want to execute this per Alt+X (I am using Dbeaver) as I want to put query into pentaho. I need to execute around 50 deletes, so I don't want to divide it on 50 SQL scripts.

I am using MySQL (version: 5.6.36-82.0).

Comment: Most database APIs only allow you to execute one query at a time.

Comment: So not clear what you are actually asking here. You say you want to delete soemthing but you show us a SELECT that fails?

Comment: Hi Riggs. Selects are just for example what kind of error is this. I have around 50 delete statements like this:
DELETE from mpanel.alias where alias_created < (SELECT CAST(DATE_SUB(NOW(),INTERVAL 2 YEAR) AS DATE));

with different databases, tables and columns, but error is still the same.

Answer (score 57):

You need to click on "Execute Script" option on DBeaver

[image]

If you click the play button, It will show you that error.

Comment: Thanks for reply, but the point is that there is no such option in Pentaho (as I mentioned in post - I need to execute it in Pentaho on "Execute SQL script" where I get same error).

Comment: I think it should be something similar, look at the documentation of pentaho, it requires precisely that lines must be separated by semicolon., maybe is just to choose the right option, or maybe you have a selected option like "Execute as a single statement" https://help.pentaho.com/Documentation/8.2/Products/Data_Integration/Transformation_Step_Reference/Execute_SQL_Script

Comment: No, any option is selected (but I tried everything - just to be sure). My query is around 50 deletes, all of them finished with semicolon.

Comment: Not sure, but maybe is possible to putthe instruction  "DELIMITER ; " at the beginning of the script to force it, Just trying to give some ideas.

Comment: Yeah, tried this as well. I also tried with different character ('$' and '$$') just to make sure, but didn't help. Anyway thanks for your time.

Answer (score 37):

If you is using Dbeaver you can select you script and press ALT+X

wrong and correct way below

[image]

Comment: been looking for this for a while,  thanks

Answer (score 0):

there must be no spaces before delimiter keyword (dbeaver bug I think)

Comment: this is not an answer on the question

Comment: if you remove spaces before delimiter keyword it works, I think this is an answer

Answer (score 0):

Recently I also needed to run several batches of selected SQL statements to update few databases and found new version shortcut key scheme in formerly convenient DBeaver **extremely annoying**. Seems someone with great influence over DBeaver developer team requested to put default SQL executing key bindings in order he wants, but what is not convenient for great majority of the rest of users. No big deal. We can thwart him back by updating DBeaver key bindings for SQL executing as we need to return DBeaver to its former glory. Let **swap Execute SQL query and Execute SQL script key bindings in DBeaver**:

1. Open DBeaver key binding dialog by menu: Window -> Preferences ->
   User interface -> Keys. Put "Execute SQL" in filter textbox above to
   see our suspects in shortcut list below.

[image]

2. In shortcut list select "Execute SQL query". Delete "Binding"
   textbox content. Then put "Alt+X" in "Binding" textbox by pressing
   `Alt` and `X` keys.
3. In shortcut list select "Execute SQL script". Delete "Binding"
   textbox content. Then put "Ctrl+Enter" in "Binding" textbox by
   pressing `Ctrl` and `Enter` keys.
4. Press `Apply and Close` button to save updated key binding scheme.

[image]

Now you should be able to execute a group of several selected SQL statements by pressing `Ctrl`+`Enter` keys again as normal people do ;)